# Envio e requisição de form via Ajax - (JavaScript puro)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Sou iniciante em JavaScript e comecei a ver Ajax.
Elaborei um exemplo onde tenho um form que envia um nome para um arquivo php.
Este php recebe via post e escreve a informação em um txt. 
Estou usando o Ajax para enviar os dados e tentando requisitá-los para aparecer em uma div, sem refresh obviamente, porém, **não estou conseguindo requisitar após envio.**

Segue os códigos

HTML

```
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
        $name = "<p>" . $_POST["name"] . "</p>" . PHP_EOL;
        $file = fopen("names.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, $name);
        fclose($file);
    ?>
```

JavaScript

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("submit"),
              result = document.getElementById("result"),
              ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    function sendData() {
        "use strict";
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        ajax.open("POST", "_names.php", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send("name=" + name);
    }

    function loadData() {
        "use strict";
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
                result.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        };
        ajax.open("POST", "names.txt", true);
        ajax.send(null);
    }

    window.onload = loadData();

    btn.onclick = function () {
        "use strict";
        sendData();
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: Qual a dúvida???

Comment: Eu consigo enviar os dados para o arquivo, mas o resultado só aparece se eu dar refresh na página. É este o problema

Comment: Se você pretende enviar e recuperar o nome, não precisa que o PHP retorne o conteúdo novamente, basta o status de sucesso... use a `var name`.

Comment: O PHP está só escrevendo a informação no txt.
O Ajax manda os dados para o php, o php armazena no txt, e em seguida o ajax busca estes dados no txt.

Comment: O PHP esta escrevendo com sucesso o nome no arquivo?

Comment: Já tentou fazer uma única requisição, e responder a partir do próprio php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há dois problemas:

**1)** A cada `sendData` é necessário chamar `loadData` para verificar os dados.

**2)** Cada requisição deve ter um novo construtor Ajax (classe chamada)

Para resolver o primeiro problema deve-se usar `onreadystatechange` na função `sendData`, dentro da `if` devemos usar `ajax.readyState` para verificar se o load está completo (lembre-se ajax é assíncrono).

Para resolver o segundo problema você deve chamar um `new XMLHttpRequest` a cada requisição.

Tente isto:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("submit"),
          result = document.getElementById("result");

function sendData() {
    "use strict";

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    ajax.open("POST", "_names.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
            loadData(); //Recarrega dados após o envio dos dados
        }
    };
    ajax.send("name=" + name);
}

function loadData() {
    "use strict";

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
            result.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    };
    ajax.open("POST", "names.txt", true);
    ajax.send(null);
}

window.onload = loadData;

btn.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    sendData();
    return false;
};
```

<s>Faltou adicionar `}` no final desta função:</s>

```
function sendData() {
        "use strict";
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        ajax.open("POST", "_names.php", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send("name=" + name);
```

E troque o `<input type=submit>` por `<input type=button>`, por que se usar submit a página vai redirecionar e o ajam será cancelado

Comment: Isso foi erro de digitação aqui no site kkk.

Nos inputs, já havia testado diferentes.
Se eu colocar "return false;" na última linha de `btn.onclick = ...` então o refresh não ocorre, porém os dados não são carregados.

Comment: Sim. Testei.
O comportamento padrão após o submit é o refresh, por isso adiciono o "return false" no `btn.onclick`, para impedir o comportamento padrão deste evento no botão.
Todavia, os dados são enviados, mas não carregados ...

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. \o/
Se puder, me explica porque esta linha aí funciona.
Tentei algo semelhante antes, rodava, mas o Firefox acusava um abort.

Comment: `ajax.onreadystatechange = loadData;`
Funcionava, mas dava um erro "erro" no Chrome.
Verificando o Network no Developer Tools, o `_names.php` dá status OK, porém o `names.txt` é (canceled).
Eu atualizava a página, e a resposta que foi enviada carregava. 
Agora, com este novo código, tudo está perfeito.
Pode explicar a razão disto?

Comment: Observando o código reparei. O erro do qual falo estava surgindo, talvez, porque havia a chamada a dois métodos `open` consecutivos.
Acredito que eles conflitavam.

Comment: Código 100%.
Então, estava pensando certo? Um mesmo objeto não pode fazer duas requisições consecutivas porque uma irá conflitar com outra?

Comment: Quase exato, não é que irá conflitar, o problema é que já foi usado, provavelmente no processo interno da API já foi setado dados, o que faria não funcionar ou funcionar parcialmente (dependendo do motor EcmaScript usado pelo navegador). Mas independente disto, sim você estava pensando certo, é necessário um objeto para cada requisição.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção e imensa ajuda Guilherme.
Desculpa por qualquer inconveniente.

Comment: Não foi nenhum inconveniente, estamos aqui para aprender e dividir conhecimento! Abraço e sucesso!

Comment: Tenha uma ótima noite. =)

Comment: Antes estava assim: 
`window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    loadComment();
};`

Agora está assim:
`window.onload = loadData;`

Este último não irá disparar o reload da página?

Comment: loadComment não está definido, não entendo aonde se aplica ele.

Comment: Desculpa, quiz dizer "loadData()".

Comment: Acredito que eu tenha entendido, mas isto estava errado window.onload = loadData(); pois ele não era chamado no onload tem que remover o () para que seja setado ao evento onload

Comment: Então, `window.onload = loadData();` lança o evento e `window.onload = loadData;`, tal como `window.onload = function { loadData(); }` seta a função ao evento?

Comment: Não no segundo exemplo é a mesma coisa, mas você cria um evento anônimo. Eu prefiro como está na resposta, assim não há necessidade de criar dois eventos. Note: evento = função.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e após o usuário selecionar como pode ser enviado esses dados selecionado para o mysql . Fica o meu caso tem como vê http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181981/form-din%C3%A2mico-e-envio-para-o-mysql-via-jquery-e-ajax?noredirect=1#comment376494_181981